# Weighted edge list from a database using R

Tags: r

I would like to use a database to create an edge list to perform network analysis.

Here are some pictures to explain what I would like to do.

The following picture is a subset of my database.

[image]

Here are the details using dput():

```
mydata <- structure(list(DoctID = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2",  
"D3", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4"), HospID = c("H1", "H2", "H4", "H1",
"H3","H1", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4"), Period1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(DoctID
=structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")),
HospID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
"collector")), Period1 = structure(list(), class =
c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(),
class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

I want to create an edge list with weights, for which two hospitals are linked if the same doctor has been to the two hospitals at period 1. If a doctor has been to a given hospital in period 1, there is 1 in the column "Period 1", otherwise there is 0. The weight corresponds to the number of doctors who have been to the two same hospitals in period 1.

That is, for instance, D1 has been to H2 and H4 in Period1, as well as D4. So the weight of the edge between H2 and H4 is 2.

Here a picture of the edge list I would like to get :

[image]

Since the network is undirected, the edge list should be symmetric.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I think `crossprod(table(yourdata))` could give you a weighted adjacency matrix, then it easy to transform but can't test. Please can you add your data in a format that it is easy to use i.e. add the results of `dput(your data)` rather than a screenshot. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update Pauline: there are a few ways to go with this. Id tend to form the adjacency matrix to be consistent with the graph  terminology. So `wadj = crossprod(table(subset(mydata, Period1 != 0)[1:2]))` forms the weighted adj matrix. You can almost get the edge list by converting it to a data.frame, using `edge = as.data.frame.table(wadj)`. Now all you need to do is subset it to remove edges with zero counts, or loop edges if required.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!